# Tableau JavaScript API - get Selected value

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I am currently researching the possibility to grabbing data from the Tableau report(s) via the JavaScript API but the closet I can get to grabbing values from a graph after filtering is selecting the value via the selectSingleValue() method.

For example: [JavaScript API Tutorial](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/samples/en-us/js_api/tutorial.htm)

In the API tutorial tab called 'Select'. One of the examples selects the row "Marcao Sao, China". Is it possible to extract that numerical value of $52.0k ?

I have tried looking into the Objects returned (via FireBug) but I cannot seem to locate the right object. My recent location was in getActiveSheets().

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JavaScript API tutorial tab 'Events' it shows you how to add an event listener to return the selected marks. You can then loop through the marks to get the values you want.

Copy the below code block into a file, save as html and open in your favourite web browser (tested on ie11).

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tableau 8 Javascrip API</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://public.tableausoftware.com/javascripts/api/tableau_v8.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/////////////////////
// Global variables
var viz, workbook, activeSheet

// function called by viz on marks being selected in the workbook
function onMarksSelection(marksEvent) {
  return marksEvent.getMarksAsync().then(reportSelectedMarks);
}

function reportSelectedMarks(marks) {
    for (var markIndex = 0; markIndex < marks.length; markIndex++) {
        var pairs = marks[markIndex].getPairs();
        for (var pairIndex = 0; pairIndex < pairs.length; pairIndex++) {
            var pair = pairs[pairIndex];
            if (pair.fieldName == "AVG(F: GDP per capita (curr $))") {
                alert("You selected a country with an avg GPD per capita of " + pair.formattedValue);
            }
        }
    }
}


// Initialise the viz to hold the workbook
function initializeViz(){
     var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz"); 
     var url = "http://public.tableausoftware.com/views/WorldIndicators/GDPpercapita?Region="; 
     var options = {
          width: "800px", //width: placeholderDiv.offsetWidth,
          height: "400px", //height: placeholderDiv.offsetHeight,
          hideTabs: true,
          hideToolbar: true,
          onFirstInteractive: function () {
                workbook = viz.getWorkbook();
                activeSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();
          }
     };
     viz = new tableauSoftware.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options);    
    // Add event listener
    viz.addEventListener(tableauSoftware.TableauEventName.MARKS_SELECTION, onMarksSelection);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Tableau view goes here -->
     <div id="tableauViz" style="height:1200px; width:1200px"\></div>
     <script type='text/javascript'>
     //Initialize the viz after the div is created
     initializeViz();
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```